# Not able to open modal window from qGrid Navigator button

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jqgrid

Using Backbone.js and jqGrid, 
I want to open a modal window for jqGrid navigator button. So I have added a button to navigator using `'navButtonAdd()'` function.

PFB the code :

```
// js function
 openEmpModal : function (){

        jQuery("#empModal").dialog();
        jQuery("#empModal").dialog("open");                 

}

// jqGrid code
         $("#empTable").navButtonAdd('#pagerTable',{
                   caption:"",
                   buttonicon:"ui-icon-gear", 
                   onClickButton: function(){ 
                      self.openEmpModal();      
                   }, 
                   position:"last"
                });

//Html code 

<div class="modal" id="empModal"><table><tr><td>Data</td></tr></table></div>
```

When clciked on the button on jqGrid navigator, it throws the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b,d){
var e=a.split(".")[0],f;a=a.split(".")[1];f=e+"-"+a;d||(d=b,b=c.Widget);
c.expr[":"][f]= function(b){
 return!!c.data(b,a)};c[e]=c[e]||{};c[e][a]=function(a,b){
 arguments.length&&this._createWidget(a,b)};b=new b;
 b.options=c.extend(!0,{},b.options);c[e][a].prototype=c.extend(!0,b, 
   {namespace:e,widgetName:a,widgetEventPrefix:c[e] 
   [a].prototype.widgetEventPrefix||a,widgetBaseClass:f},d);
  c.widget.bridge(a,c[e][a])} has no method 'extend' jquery-ui-custom.min.js:6
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, The issue got solved. The UI was built using Bootstrap.js. Now able to open modal window using bootstrap code in Javascript

$('#myModal').modal({
  keyboard: false
})